# Outsider interested in or specialising in art

Tags: pathfinder-1e, lore, golarion, forgotten-realms

I'm looking for a type of Outsider with a racial focus on the arts (ideally the visual arts) - preferably from Golarion, but I'd take something good from other lore also such as from Faerun or elsewhere.

The situation is to be akin to the greek myth of Arachne (except I'm after something I can reasonably pitch against a party at around level 10).

Ideally I'd like a type of Outsider whose purpose, raison d'être or racial function was art - if that makes sense.

Comment: I'll assume a outsider turned lich who happens to like art is out of the question?  (Just to clarify the scope)

Comment: Ideally I'm after an outsider species(?) with a racial focus on art, rather than an individual. Preferably with some character to them that could be bent towards an Arachne like situation.

Comment: What kind of arts are acceptable? Visual arts only, or performance also?

Comment: Ah, yes - I was particularly looking for the visual arts. Apologies; I have edited that into the question. Though I could get performance art to work, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Paizo publication, "Chronicle of the Righeous" has descriptions on several outsiders.

### Outsiders Explicitly Interested in Art

[Angels](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/angel) are often inspired by the dreams of mortal to create artwork in the Ethereal plane.

> The drifting dreams of mortals often inspire angels passing through to create phantasmagorical works of art.
>
> These living sculptures, paintings, and melodies swirl around the bastion in an scintillating haze of insubstantial monuments, colors, and sounds.

[Archons](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/archon) are described as having an interest in architecture, especially a particular symmetric and grand style.

[Azata](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/azata) love art. They build fantastical homes and furnish them with different art forms. Further, they organize into "courts" which are centered on particular artistic media or styles.

> They make their homes in fantastic structures, from heavy silk tents embroidered with spun gemstones to lofty bamboo palaces. Most azatas maintain multiple homes and change locations frequently in accordance with their shifting alliances within azata society. These alliances— called courts—center on art, music, philosophy, and personal taste, and spring up almost as quickly as they dissolve. Though a few permanent courts exist in Elysium, their membership changes like the plane's fickle winds.

If you want something more villainous, consider [Asura](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/asura).  The description doesn't explicitly say they favor artistry, however the *flavor* of the text certainly paints that picture.  Asura are contemplative and focused, often philosophical.  They brood over their feelings of rejection.  And they are evil - generally focused on destroying the cosmos.

Comment: I was reluctant to accept this because I need them to be spiteful, and none of these fit that description - so far as I can see, but I may be able to get it to work with a slightly insane Lillend or something.

Comment: I've added Asura to the list. They aren't explicitly artists, but their description makes them an excellent choice for an artistic outsider villain.